# Apple added new Key to the provisioning file

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, appstore-approval, ios-provisioning

Apple recently (In May or June 2015) added a following key on provisioning file  :

```
<key>Platform</key>
   <array>
      <string>iOS</string>
   </array>
```

Does anyone know why apple add this key? Did they add it in any documentation?

Last year Apple added a new entitlement called **beta-reports-active** without any notice which when it was missing on the .mobileprovision apps got rejected, Does apple have a same plan? does this key related to new Xcode and iOS 9 ?

Should we update all provision files for having this key?